# Programa nao para o laço, mesmo digitando a tecla para interromper!

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int codigo;
    char departamento;
    char nome[30];
    float salario;
}DadosFuncionario;

int main () {
    FILE *fp;
    DadosFuncionario funcionario;
    char nome_arquivo[]= "saida.txt";
    char sair;

    fp = fopen(nome_arquivo, "w");


    do {
        printf("Codigo do Funcionario:\n");
        scanf("%d", &funcionario.codigo);

        printf("Departamento:\n");
        scanf(" %c", &funcionario.departamento);

        printf("Nome:\n");
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", funcionario.nome);

        printf("Salario:\n");
        scanf("%f", &funcionario.salario);

        fwrite(&funcionario, sizeof(DadosFuncionario),1,fp);

        printf("Deseja sair (s/S):");
        scanf("%c", &sair);

        }while(sair!= 's' && sair!='S');

        fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Creio que você está tendo problema com caractere ENTER da entrada anterior que não é consumido e permanece  no buffer do teclado. Você pode descartar este '\n' com: while((sair = getchar()) != '\n' && sair != EOF)
   /* descarta o caractere lido */ ;. Existem outras maneiras de fazer.

Comment: De uma maneira mais simples coloque um espaço antes do %c: scanf(" %c", &sair); que o caractere de nova linha será consumido.

Answer (score 0):

Em vez de ser `&&` no while, deverá ser `||`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int codigo;
    char departamento;
    char nome[30];
    float salario;
}DadosFuncionario;

int main () {
    FILE *fp;
    DadosFuncionario funcionario;
    char nome_arquivo[]= "saida.txt";
    char sair;

    fp = fopen(nome_arquivo, "w");


    do {
        printf("Codigo do Funcionario:\n");
        scanf("%d", &funcionario.codigo);

        printf("Departamento:\n");
        scanf(" %c", &funcionario.departamento);

        printf("Nome:\n");
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", funcionario.nome);

        printf("Salario:\n");
        scanf("%f", &funcionario.salario);

        fwrite(&funcionario, sizeof(DadosFuncionario),1,fp);

        printf("Deseja sair (s/S):");
        scanf("%c", &sair);

        }while(sair!= 's' || sair!='S');

        fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Neste caso basta digitar ou 's' ou 'S' que continuará executando o loop. Tem que ser && mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Coloque um espaço antes do %c

```
printf("Deseja sair (s/S):");
scanf(" %c", &sair);
```